# powershell - Regular expression to match a string which equilevent to like statment in sql

Tags: regex, powershell

In regex, how to match a string then has this pattern ? In sql it mean match string like `%Asia%SouthEast%`

```
*Asia*SouthEast*
```

Example

```
Asia 2 SouthEast 9 --> false  
This is Asia 2 and SouthEast 9 --> true
Asia SouthEast --> true **There a space after SouthEast
```

Comment: In which language? Regex is a very generic tag. You do have to specify the language you are working on.

Comment: Are you sure that the sql like expression would match the first example as false? I think it will return true for both cases because the % sign is a character wildcard and should be equal to the * sign in regexps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples I infer that you necessarily need 1 or more characters before and after each of these words: `Asia` and `SouthEast`.

For that you can use this regex:

`.+Asia.+SouthEast.+`

Sample:

```
> "Asia 2 SouthEast 9" -match ".+Asia.+SouthEast.+"
False
> "This is Asia 2 and SouthEast 9" -match ".+Asia.+SouthEast.+"
True
```

or

```
> "Asia 2 SouthEast 9" -match "[\w\s]+Asia[\w\s]+SouthEast[\w\s]+"
False
> "This is Asia 2 and SouthEast 9" -match "[\w\s]+Asia[\w\s]+SouthEast[\w\s]+"
True
```

Comment: I also want the reg return true if string is Asia SouthEast **There a single space after SouthEast

Comment: @user664481 then you'll have to use this:  `.*Asia.*SouthEast.+`